# Passing parameters in function and then calling function onClick

Tags: javascript, android, function

I'm trying to get a button to call on a function. The only problem is, the function calls a parameter from another function and I'm getting an error: SetRecipe (int) in AddRecipe cannot be applied to (). I have no idea what I'm meant to pass/call whatever the correct terminology is.

The button code is:

```
    Button saveRecipe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddRecipe);
    saveRecipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SetRecipe();
        }
    });
```

And the functions are:

```
public int getDifficulty (View v)
{
    int Difficulty = -1;
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) v).isChecked();
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnDiff1:
            if (checked)
                Difficulty = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.btnDiff2:
            if (checked)
                Difficulty = 2;
            break;
        case R.id.btnDiff3:
            if (checked)
                Difficulty = 3;
            break;
        case R.id.btnDiff4:
            if (checked)
                Difficulty = 4;
            break;
        case R.id.btnDiff5:
            if (checked)
                Difficulty = 5;
            break;
    }

    return Difficulty;
}

public void SetRecipe (int Difficulty)
{
    TextView RecipeNameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editRecipeName);
    TextView CookTimeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editCookTime);
    Spinner MealTypeView = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.editMeal);
    TextView HowToView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editHowTo);

    String RecipeName = RecipeNameView.getText().toString();
    int CookTime = Integer.parseInt(CookTimeView.getText().toString());
    String MealType = MealTypeView.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String HowTo = HowToView.getText().toString();


    DatabaseHandler dbh = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    dbh.SetRecipe(RecipeName, CookTime, Difficulty, MealType, HowTo);

}
```

All I'm looking to do is get the int Difficulty from the getDifficulty function and pass it to the SetRecipe function. The SetRecipe function will then be called on when the user hits a button.

If it's a silly mistake then I do apologise, I am extremely new to coding and so I don't really know what I'm doing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying Difficulty = 1, 2, 3,4 Can you call it directly?

```
SetRecipe(1);
```

Also...when I implement View.OnClickListener...

```
public class yourclass extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
Button setrecipe1;
Button setrecipe2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

    setrecipe1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.setrecipe1);
    setrecipe2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.setrecipe2);
    setrecipe1.setOnClickListener(this);
    setrecipe2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.setrecipe1:
            SetRecipe(1);
            break;
        case R.id.setrecipe2:
            SetRecipe(2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
}
}
}
```

Comment: What control are you getting the difficulty integer from?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `android:onClick="getDifficulty"` attribute to the btnAddRecipe tag and remove the onClickListener...
This should work

Answer (score 0):

before your `OnCreate` method declare:

```
int Difficulty;
```

in your `getDifficulty` method remove the `int`:

```
int Difficulty = -1;  ==> Difficulty = -1;
```

then inside your click button :

```
Button saveRecipe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddRecipe);
saveRecipe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SetRecipe(Difficulty);
    }
});
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi! I've tried this but when I pull the database from ADM and open it up, 0 is the value being placed into the database, no matter what difficulty I choose. I have no idea where it's getting the value 0 from either...

Comment: there is no error or `NullPointerExcpetion`?.. try to declare before your OnCreate method something like:

`int Difficulty = 1;`  and let me know

Comment: Yeah it's being stored as 1 now. The value of the difficulty is not being passed but I can't figure out why :(

Comment: your `getDifficulty` method is not been called, please edit your question with all your `activity`